# What are s-bands and d-bands in band structures?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, orbitals, dispersion, fermi-energy

Given a band structure diagrams I can understand whether there are band gaps and what the bands are but what are s-bands and d-bands and how do I tell them apart in these diagrams?

Example:
[image]

I understand since there are no band gaps that these are both metals and the density is highest for A around the Fermi energy and for B a little below. However, I cannot distinguish different bands.

Comment: Are you trying to relate atomic orbitals to band structure?

Comment: I am not sure, in the book I'm reading they keep talking about s-bands and d-bands crossing the Fermi energy level relating to effective masses.